# How a dynamic dns provider update my IP for the subdomain he gave me?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, dns-hosting

No-ip and dyndns, for example, give me a subdomain which will point to my latest IP address. However, how do they update the IP for this subdomain?

One method would be to ask the registar for this domain to update it for me, but this would take hours to propagate globally. However, my IP changes many times a day and I don't even notice the dynamic dns domain beig unresponsive until the next propagation.

This makes me think that another technology is being used. How it is done? Can I run one privately for subdomains of my domain?

Comment: Typically, I believe, this doesn't happen.  Have you checked the reverse entry for your current IP address to see what it actually is?

Comment: @HarryJohnston reverse entry for IP address? It says that there are no domains registered for it

Answer (score 1):

They're simply a [DNS service](https://dyn.com/dynamic-dns/) that is set up to deal with regular changes. They run a DNS server that has entries with a short TTL, 1 minute or 5 minutes I guess.

When your IP changes the [software you run on your PC](https://dyn.com/update-client-faqs/) sends an update to them, which makes a change to their DNS server. As soon as the cached DNS entry expires on the client they request your IP address from the server again.

If you look up your domain name using [Network Tools](https://network-tools.com/) it will tell you the TTL and may make it more clear to you how this works.

Comment: if they're a DNS service, shouldn't I have their DNS service IP on my computer's DNS entry? How do a random computer know that it must query the DNS from their DNS service?

Comment: @guerlando that's the whole idea behind DNS - irrespective of where the authorative source for your dns name sits, the entire internet will be able to use that information...

Comment: so my new IP gets propagated to the entire internet? How could I make my own DNS service and propagate my own names?

Comment: I really think you need to do some more reading to understand how DNS and IP addresses work on the internet. I did a quick search, [this](https://computer.howstuffworks.com/dns1.htm) and [this](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/internet-intro/internet-works-intro/v/the-internet-ip-addresses-and-dns) might be useful.